# Large dataset for network charts in javascript

Tags: javascript, data-visualization

I'm aiming to render between 500,000 - 1 million records displayed in a network chart in Javascript.
First of all, I'm wondering if there's a library in Javascript that could render such amount of data at one go, since the entire data needs to be displayed at once. Then, I'm also wondering if there's a better alternative in Flash (or any other).

Im practically looking to build something like the LinkedIn's InMap:
http://www.fastcodesign.com/1663098/infographic-of-the-day-linkedin-maps-big-shots-in-your-social-network

So, how feasible is for a large dataset to be rendered in network charts within Javascript? is there any library to hold such amount? and if it's not, any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do aggregation of some kind. Even desktop network analysis tools will have difficulty rendering a node-link diagram with a million nodes. That's not to mention the fact that a diagram with that many nodes will be impossible to to understand.

Here are some example academic articles on various way to do aggregation. The first two focus on grouping nodes by their categorical attributes to show overall relationships, and the last talks about how to create a "back-bone" network that shows the key features.

- Martin Wattenberg. 2006. Visual exploration of multivariate graphs. In Proceedings of the SIGCHI conference on Human Factors in computing systems (CHI '06), 811-819. [DOI=10.1145/1124772.1124891](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1124772.1124891). [PDF](http://hint.fm/papers/pivotgraph.pdf)
- Cody Dunne, Nathalie Henry Riche, Bongshin Lee, Ronald Metoyer, and George Robertson. 2012. GraphTrail: analyzing large multivariate, heterogeneous networks while supporting exploration history. In Proceedings of the 2012 ACM annual conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems (CHI '12), 1663-1672. [DOI=10.1145/2208276.2208293](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2208276.2208293). [PDF](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~cdunne/hcil/pubs/Dunne12GraphTrail_analyzinglarge.pdf)
- Pak Chung Wong, Harlan Foote, Patrick Mackey, George Chin, Heidi Sofia, and Jim Thomas. 2008. A dynamic multiscale magnifying tool for exploring large sparse graphs. Information Visualization 7, 2 (April 2008), 105-117. [DOI=10.1057/palgrave.ivs.9500177](http://dx.doi.org/10.1057/palgrave.ivs.9500177). [PDF](https://www.purdue.edu/discoverypark/vaccine/assets/pdfs/publications/pdf/A%20Dynamic%20Multiscale%20Magnifying.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the above, just for the record: we used D3.js as it proved to be the most stable library and we were able to render 100,000 + nodes and their relationships, however as you cleverly stated,  the diagram pretty much made no sense after 20,000 nodes.